# Angular multiple file upload not working as expected

Tags: angular

When i try to upload multiple files in formdata, then the api returns an empty arrays. (Working with postman)

Can you tell me why? Thanks!

**Heres my code:**

**Add file function (saves the file, a filename, and a preview for the client):**

```
  addFile(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.files)

    Array.from(event.target.files).forEach((fileData: any) => {
      let fileName = fileData.name;

      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener(
        'load',
        () => {
          // convert image file to base64 string
          this.draftImages.push({
            preview: reader.result,
            file: fileData,
            fileName: fileName
          })
        },
        false
      );

      if (fileData) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileData);
      }
    });
  }
```

**Upload file function to api:**

```
      let formData = new FormData()

      let files: any = []


      this.draftImages.forEach((fileData: any) => {
        files.push(fileData.file)
        console.log(fileData.file);
      })

      formData.append("file", files)

      this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:3000/chat/message/dm/uploadImg", formData).subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result, formData)
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

changed

```
      this.draftImages.forEach((fileData: any) => {
        files.push(fileData.file)
        console.log(fileData.file);
      })
```

**to**

```
      formData.append("file", fileData.file, fileData.name)
        console.log(fileData.file);
      })
```